# What word is the positive equivalent of flattery?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

The word flattery depicts much heavier compliments and praise than either "compliment" or "praise".

Is there a word with similar (or close) intensity as flattery without the insincerity component?

The intended usage is in an informal setting such as "She warmed up to him as a result of all his unabashed compliments to her". "Compliment" here feels too dilute. "Praise" on the other hand feels somewhat detached.

Comment: No; you've said it. Praise. But you're perhaps worried about the 'gushing / over-the-top' flavour that this can carry, because of religious usage,  and you would be right to be so.  And perversely, the word has at the same time in certain contexts been rather devalued of weight, as you say. Use carefully.

Comment: Hi @KalenGi can you please confirm whether the required term is for formal or informal use? Adding an example sentence to your question would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: @JulieCarter I've added more context.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of the word flattery. I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Flattery can be sincere. "Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery."

Comment: I wouldn't avoid flatter where context indicated sincerity. It emphasizes how the comment is meant to make someone feel. Motives are another matter entirely.

Comment: Annoyingly, applaud would work as a verb, but applause won't work as a noun. I hate it when that happens.

Comment: "She warmed up to him because he genuinely admired her."

Answer (score 6):

Consider *[accolade](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/accolade)*

> strong praise or approval; acclaim

*Collins*

It tends to be used in more formal settings and is usually reserved for high praise.

Comment: Accolades are usually given by organisations or at awards though, aren't they?

Comment: @Deonyi While that may be a more common usage, I surely have heard the term used with praise from individuals. A show might receive accolades from the critics, or even a strong word-of-mouth support.

Comment: I suppose; I associate it with a lot of clapping too, such as at awards and shows.

Answer (score 3):

A formal term,  ***[encomium](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encomium)*** carries the connotation you are referring to:

> - glowing and warmly enthusiastic praise; also :  an expression of this.

(M-W)

Comment: Use _very_ carefully.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why so careful?

Comment: @Dan Bron OP wants to use this in an informal setting. I would only use it in a crossword.

Answer (score 1):

A ***eulogy*** involves commending the character and services of a person, or the qualities of a thing. Although eulogies are most commonly in honour of a dead person, they may be said (even 'sung') to commend, extol, and praise the achievements of living individuals. (OED)

Answer (score 1):

How about **a dithyramb**? (rare in English but more common in French, especially the adjective, *dithyrambique*, English *dithyrambic*)

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dithyramb) defines it as:

> 1. a usually short poem in an inspired wild irregular strain
> 2. a statement or writing in an exalted or enthusiastic vein
>
> example sentence: a tongue-in-cheek *dithyramb* of the chocolate chip cookie

The idea is that the speaker or writer is so enthusiastic about the thing or person they are singing the praise of that they get carried away, they wax lyrical; but there is no idea of flattery, no hypocrisy involved.